# Internal server Error while accessing a php page in apache2

Tags: server, apache2, php

After install apache2 it work fine, but if reinstall php5 that the server doesn't work, if I try to access `http://127.0.0.1` a give the error 500, or a file of www folder, if I try to access a folder or a file of a folder all work fine.
Error 500 details:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/test.php

500 Internal Server Error Запрос GET /test.php HTTP/1.1 User-Agent:

Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16 Host:

localhost Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1 Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Ответ HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 19:16:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html
```

Not error 500:

```
 GET http://127.0.0.1/css/


200 OK
GET /css/ HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16
Host: localhost Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive Ответ HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 19:21:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 648 Keep-Alive: timeout=5,max=99
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> [...]
```

Comment: What's the content of `test.php`?

Comment: It is a simple file, it contains "<? php_info() ?>"

Comment: Did you enable short execution tags in the server configuration? Try `<?php php_info(); ?>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an error in your PHP File, a PHP Info file should be:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

`<?` id depreciated as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/200666

`php_info()` is an incorrect function name  (unless you have coded this yourself), and should have a closing semi-colon (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: Work with "<?php"; Can I set php5 to can use only "<?"? In windows I use openserver(with php 5.4) and all work fine with "<?". `PHP Version 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3,`

Comment: You can indeed (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) however I wouldn't recommend it, your code is then no longer as easily portable when moving between machines...